# Does Unicode guarantee that numeral codepoints are consecutive?

Tags: unicode

Is the constructiveness of numeral codepoints guaranteed in the Unicode standard?

From the scripts that I've manually checked, they are indeed consecutive (U+30 to U+39 for basic laten and U+2080 to U+2089 for subscripts). However, there are too many numeral sets in the unicode standard for me to check by hand, and doing so says nothing about feature additions.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. For example Suzhou numerals are spread between a bunch of different code points.

All you ever wanted to know about Unicode numerals is here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode